# Python Modify List outside scope of a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a function defined outside of class scope in Python, and it modifies the passed value, without any references to the passed variable, but somehow the original variable in class scope gets modified.

I have used python extensively for scriting but haven't really done much with Classes. I looked at [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) post, which explains a lot but doesn't really talk about it. This variable is surely out of scope, how's it getting mutated?

```
def doSomethingOutOfScope(arr):
    spv = arr[0]
    arr[0] = 'S'


class Solution:
    def doSomethingInScope(self, passed_arr):
        print(passed_arr)                  # prints [0, 1, 2]
        doSomethingOutOfScope(passed_arr)  # passed_arr shouldn't get modified
        print(passed_arr)                  # prints ['S', 1, 2] - Why ?

s = Solution()
s.doSomethingInScope([0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythons list are actually mutable and are passed by reference

Answer (score 3):

In Python, everything is an object and **every object is passed in reference**.  Therefore basically any changes you directly made on the passed object *besides reassigning* is always reflected on the object itself in real time.  The key thing to note is the *mutability* of the object, i.e. whether the object is mutable pass its initial assignment.

For example, `str` and `int` objects are immutable.  Note there are never any methods under `str` and `int` that changes the object directly:

```
s = 'foo'  # str type
s.upper()  # FOO
print(s)
# foo
```

Note how `str.upper()` method doesn't change `s` itself.   in order to make `s` into "FOO", you need to *reassign* `s`:

```
s = s.upper()
print(s)
# FOO
```

However by reassigning the object (`obj = ...`) it changes the object reference, where `id(s)` will now be different.  So if a `str` was passed like this:

```
def func(string):
    string = string.upper()

func(s)
```

`s` will remain unchanged because at the point of reassignment `string = ...`, `string` will no longer have the same object reference of `s`.

However, with mutable objects, as long as you don't reassign, the object itself will take the changes:

```
l = list('abcde')
def func(lst, value):
    lst.append(value)
    # no reassignment

func(l, 'f')
print(l)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

That is because the object reference (`id(l)`) remains the same within the function.

---

All that said, in your case, if you wanted to do something with the object but not mutate it, you want to either pass a *copy* of the object (which will have a different `id`), or create a copy of the passed object in the local scope:

```
# pass a copy of the object:
def func(lst):
    lst.append('x')
    return lst

func(lst[:])

# OR, create a local object
def out_of_scope(lst):
    temp_lst = lst[:]
    temp_lst.append('x')
    return temp_lst
```

In this particular case, `[:]` returns a full `slice` of the `list` as a different object.

For a bit more information, here's a [relevant read](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/).